# iPhone: UIImageView Fades in - Howto?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, xamarin.ios

I have an `UIImageView` that I want to fade in.

Is there a way to enable that on an underlying `UIViewController`?

I have translated the simplest answer, though they all work, `C# .NET` for the `MonoTouch` users:

```
public override void ViewDidAppear (bool animated)
{
    base.ViewDidAppear (animated);
    UIView.BeginAnimations ("fade in");
    UIView.SetAnimationDuration (1);
    imageView.Alpha = 1;
    UIView.CommitAnimations ();
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Initially set the alpha of your imageview as 0 as `imageView.alpha = 0;`

```
- (void)fadeInImage 
{
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fade in" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    imageView.alpha = 1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 23):

Change the animation duration to what ever length you want.

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]];
myImageView.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
myImageView.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
     myImageView.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

Comment: IS it possible to only animate the UIImageView and not the UIView? (and if so how?)

Comment: worked for me: I've added a `UIImageView` from the UI editor and after _(i needed to fade out the imageview)_ simply added the last 3 rows of the example _(with alpha = 0.0)_ and is ok!

Answer (score 4):

Use below in your `UIViewController`

```
// add the image view
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
// set up a transition animation
CATransition *animate = [CATransition animation];
[animate setDuration:self.animationDelay];
[animate setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animate setSubtype:kCATransitionFade];
[animate setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

[[self layer] addAnimation:animate forKey:@"fade in"];
```

Answer (score 4):

this simple code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        theImage.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
```

the `UIImage` is in the view and is connected via an `IBOutlet`
you can also, set the alpha from the utility panel.

Answer (score 1):

I would use UIView's +transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:
It is very efficient and powerful.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:imgView duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage"];
} completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

Fade In Animation:

```
self.yourComponent.alpha = 0.0f;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeIn" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; // Time in seconds
self.yourComponent.alpha = 1.0f;
```

Fade Out Animation:

```
self.yourComponent.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOut" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; // Time in seconds
self.yourComponent.alpha = 0.0f;
```

`self.yourComponent` can be a `UIView`, `UIImageView`, `UIButton` or any other component.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift version**

```
func fadeIn(){
    UIView.beginAnimations("fade in", context: nil);
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(1.0);
    imageView.alpha = 1.0;
    UIView.commitAnimations();
}
```