# Fade part of a UIImage in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage

My application is mainly based on image processing.

In my application i want to fade a part of a circular area of UIImage.
The circle can be draggable any where on the image.

Please tell me is it possible to fade a part of the image.
If yes can any one give some idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through core image filter refrence

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346
this may help you

Comment: What do you want exactly ?
Do you want to make fade your background image where you drag your cirleImage only for visibility or permanent ? visibility like drag a lance on image and permanently - like eraser. What do you want ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5632437/1059705

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this the easy way.
Put 2 `UIImageView`s on top of eachother. And add a (round) mask to the upper view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7228648/696440